# Integer-array for image in xml using in gridview

Tags: android-layout

i m trying giving integer value image using in gridview.bt i couldnt get .

this is my values/string.xml

```
<integer-array name="anim">
    <item >@drawable/goat1</item>
    <item >@drawable/lamb1</item>
    <item>@drawable/bear</item>
    <item>@drawable/lion</item>
</integer-array>
```

this is my java code:

public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

```
     **int[] anim=getResources().getIntArray(R.array.anim);**

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
```

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { 
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(anim[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use TypedArray,
TypedArray icons;
Resources res = getResources();
icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.img);
```

Then in image adapter, instead of `imageView.setImageResource(anim[position]);` :

```
Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(position);
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: If the answer helped you a good way to say thank you is by accepting the answer as correct. It will provide the user with points in addition to removing question from the unanswered questions list.